# Logic Pro X Long Recording - Static Clicks While Speaking

Tags: recording, logic-pro, clicks

I recently recorded an interview in Logic Pro X which lasted for over an hour.  Before the actual interview, I had run several short ~2 minute tests to ensure the recording was working properly.  And my tests were good, I was able to confirm that the playback sounded good on my recordings.

However, on the real recording, which lasted for 1 hr, upon playback I heard noise (static/click) starting about 11 mins into the recording! :( The first 10 mins sounded great and without problems until 11 mins into the recording.  The rest of the recording from 11 mins to 60 mins in has the same staticky/clicking noise sounds.  I was so frustrated, as the recorded material cannot be used nor edited around.

**Hardware / Software Context**

- iMac 27", Physical Drive (1TB) (APPLE HDD ST1000DM003)
- Audio Interface: Focusrite Scarlett 2i4

  - Recording on 2 XLR inputs simultaneously
- Logic Pro X v10.3.2

  - Using Aggregate Device
  - Using Multi-Output Device

**More Context**

I had attempted to also record a 3rd input, the computer audio, to capture the Google Hangout with which we were conducting the interview with Soundflower.  But, I wasn't able to record any computer audio with Logic Pro X and Soundflower in my short tests.

- Soundflower v2.0b2
- Google Hangout running
- Aggregate Device (for Scarlett 2i4 USB, Soundflower (2ch))

  - Clock Source: Soundflower
- Multi-Output Device (for Scarlett 2i4 USB, Soundflower (2ch))

  - Clock Source: Soundflower

NOTE: We were monitoring the audio via the audio interface (rather than through Logic Pro X), and thus didn't hear any issues while recording.

**Example**
This is what I heard after 11 mins into the recording. I notice the static *usually* occurs when talking.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oaRjXl94xxGKogXQgHFIrL8ouh2i2l2E/view?usp=sharing

---

**Q)** Would you listen to the sample, and tell me what you believe the cause may be?

**Q)** Any suggestion on debugging?

Comment: First test would be to get rid of Soundflower, it's been horribly unstable since about Mavericks. I don't know of any free equivalent, but 'best in show' are both from Rogue Amoeba, [Loopback](https://www.rogueamoeba.com/loopback/) or [Audio Hijack](https://rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/) depending on your requirements - see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/271164/split-input-channels-using-soundflower-and-aulab/271194#271194 & https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/203004/nice-audio-mixer-repeater/203009#203009 for examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A Solution**

Well, I was able to remove the noise static/clicking by changing the Aggregate Device *Clock Source* to Scarlett 2i4 USB.

Using Logic Pro X's *Input Monitoring* per track, I was able to hear the difference while recording.

Retoon Plays has a solution...

---

NOTE: And I also figured out how to record the computer system audio.  My missing step was to set Mac System Output to *Multi-Output Device* or at least something including Soundflower (2ch).  Formerly I was only toying with my DAW's input and output.